# Macbook shows executable file instead of folder

Tags: photos, data-recovery

I'm looking at photos on a memory stick and the mac has frozen a couple of times   - when it unfreezes the file has changed and I can't access the folder again.  Please can someone help get the photos back as they're of my kids...

[image: Screenshot of new file type]

This is what it shows on Terminal when I try to open it:

[image: Screenshot of terminal output]

Comment: It is best to paste in the text of the terminal output, rather than a screenshot, as images are not text-searchable

Comment: @Greenonline In this particular case, the terminal is a complete red herring. The data is damaged, causing the Mac to consider what was presumably a folder to now be an executable. It isn't, so it runs 'nothing'.

Comment: @Tetsujin - that sounds pretty bad to my simple mind... Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I would be tempted to take it straight to a data recovery company, assuming you have no backups. It sounds like the card is failing - sometimes these things go down fast once they go, so you don't want to do anything to further prompt it. In future, never commit the only copy of any data to something as fragile as USB stick/SD card.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can find locally

Comment: Was this USB stick formatted on a Windows machine?

Comment: @IconDaemon it was - I managed to get it into a data recovery place on Saturday, fingers crossed they can do something...

Comment: Good luck, Nunu73! After losing a small amount some irreplaceable data from a USB drive years ago, I've augmented my routine for storing similar data, documents and photos by storing it all in multiple cloud instances (iCloud, Google Drive, Evernote) and by maintaining off-site backups of the same data on external SSD drives at my office. I also have multiple Time Machine drives (off-site as well.) Should the same catastrophe befall my house _and_ my workplace, I'll have much more to worry about than retaining the data. :-)